# PleaseWaitHelper and PleaseWaitWindow Not Working

Tags: catel

I am having an issue with the `PleaseWaitHelper` properties that control the `PleaseWaitWindow`. The `PleaseWaitHelper.MinimumDurationBeforeShow` and `PleaseWaitHelper.MinimumShowTime` do not seem to be working. I am reading data from a web service and the first retrieval is slow so I want the `PleaseWaitWindow` to display. Further retrievals are quite quick so I do not want the `PleaseWaitWindow` to show.  I have the following code...

```
PleaseWaitHelper.MinimumDurationBeforeShow = 100000;
PleaseWaitHelper.MinimumShowTime = 0;
PleaseWaitWindow.Mode = PleaseWaitMode.Nothing;
PleaseWaitHelper.Show(status);
```

I am setting the value for `PleaseWaitHelper.MinimumDurationBeforeShow` deliberately high for testing. My actual value will be around 1000ms (1 second). With the setting of 100000 (100 seconds) I would expect the `PleaseWaitWindow` to never show in my app because the first time data is retrieved it never takes 100 seconds.

My questions are...

- Am I using these properties correctly and is my code correct?
- Is the `PleaseWaitHelper` and/or the `PleaseWaitWindow` broken?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's recommended to use the IPleaseWaitService instead. Then you can always replace it with any busy indicator at a later time.

It looks like you are using the code correctly. If you think you found a bug, please report it in the official [issue tracker](http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker/).

Comment: I tried using the IPleaseWaitService, however it does not support the `MinimumDurationBeforeShow`, `MinimumShowTime` properties exposed by `PleaseWaitHelper` and the `Mode` property exposed by `PleaseWaitWindow`. Digging through the source code, I now also see that the `MinimumDurationBeforeShow` and `MinimumShowTime` properties are only used if you pass in a `PleaseWaitWorkDelegate` which I am not doing. I will try the delegate approach. Thanks.